connect alb with nlb, apigetway and ec2
I am currently creating a stack in aws cdk and I have already created the ec2 instance, the alb, the nlb and the apigateway but when I want to use my apigateway to make calls to the backend I only get "message": "Internal server error" I don't know what I need to configure I have already configured port 80 and I can't get communication.
const alb = new ApplicationLoadBalancer(scope, params.applicationLoadBalancerName, {
  vpc,
  loadBalancerName: params.applicationLoadBalancerName,
  internetFacing: true,
});

const listenerInsecure = alb.addListener('Connector vcp', {
  port: 80,
  protocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
  open: true,
});

listenerInsecure.addAction('VPC Redirect', {
  action: ListenerAction.redirect({
    protocol: ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
    port: '443',
    permanent: true,
  })
}); 

const nlb = new NetworkLoadBalancer(scope, 'NLB', {
  vpc,
  internetFacing: true,
  loadBalancerName: `network-${params.applicationLoadBalancerName}`,
});

const nlbListener = nlb.addListener('nlbListener', {
  port: 80,
});

const nlbTargetGroup = new NetworkTargetGroup(scope, `NLBTargetGroup-${params.environment}`, {
  port: 80,
  vpc: vpc,
  targets: [new AlbTarget(alb, 80)],
});

nlbListener.addTargetGroups(`NLBAddingTargetGroup-${params.environment}`, nlbTargetGroup);


I am testing the connection with apigateway.

Are you explicitly setting security groups / adding your instance to the ALB's target group? Are you using default vpc/default security groups? In the console are your NLB/ALB target groups healthy?
